# Repeatedly adding list content to excel

Tags: c#, excel, list, sequential

I hope you can help me out. My problem is that I don't know how to dump the information from a list to an existent excel file.I have an int list (L1) as a part of a large code. This code adds information to the list (3 numbers), then should copy them to an excel file without overwriting the existent content (that is the bit I don't know), clear the list and repeat the process.  In other words, the process is as follows:

```
   1- I add stuff to L1                                        //I know how to do this
   2- I dump stuff to excel                                    //HOW?
   3- I clear L1                                               //I know how to do this
   4- I add new stuff to L1                                    //I know how to do this
   5- I dump stuff to excel starting in the following line     //HOW?
   6- I clear L1                                               //I know how to do this
   ...
```

The final excel should look like this (including the words Start and End):

```
    A      B       C
    Start                     //List1 is copied below
    15     18   0                     
    20     40   50
    12     15   16
    End                       //List1 is cleared
    Start       
    7      90   16            //List1 is copied below
    20     15   50
    12     15   8
    End                       //List1 is cleared
```

To write in the excel I am using something like:

```
  string path = @"C:\file.xlsx";
        oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        oXL.Visible = true;
        oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;
        mWorkBook = oXL.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
        //Get all the sheets in the workbook
        mWorkSheets = mWorkBook.Worksheets;
        //Get the allready exists sheet
        mWSheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)mWorkSheets.get_Item("Sheet1");
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = mWSheet1.UsedRange;
        int colCount = range.Columns.Count;
        int rowCount = range.Rows.Count;
```

but I do not know how to retrieve the last existing data cell and how to create the excel as shown above.

Can someone help me with the excel part please?

Thank you!!

Comment: Look into Open XML SDK... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670141/Read-and-Write-Microsoft-Excel-with-Open-XML-SDK

Comment: Do you have a method that currently writes to an excel file or do you need to code that from scratch? If you do, your problem statement gets condensed to "finding the last existing data cell". Is that correct?

Comment: GVashist, I have edited the post showing what I use to write to the  excel file. I do need to find the last existing data cell and also to write the data in the format shown above. Thank you!